# Реализовать целочисленную функцию, вычисляющую на основе входного множества :

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как переложить эти переменные на код питона, в ум не возьму что такое ф которое принадлежит Ф
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6gL2.png)

```
main({96, 35, -60, 37, 5, -90, -54, 42, 52, 21}) = -346; 
main({32, 3, -61, -85, -79, -73, 62, 89, -2, -33}) = -376
```

Comment: Хорошее задание, реализовывать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.